# Transform text while the cursor is over an image

Tags: css

I would like to change list text while the mouse is over an image, my list contains items + icons both of them with an Id :

```
s[i++] = '<li id=\"'+  vizList[j].name +'\">';
s[i++] =  '<a>'+ vizList[j].name + '</a>';
s[i++] =  '<img id="img" src="../renderer/bundles/' + vizList[j].icon + '" width="268" height="120" style="display:block"/>';
s[i++] = '</li>';
```

and my CSS is like:

```
#listLumira li a {
  display: block ;
  background: #4682B4 ;
  color: #fff ;
  font: 1em "Trebuchet MS",Arial,sans-serif ;
  line-height: 2em ;
  text-align: center ;
  text-decoration: none ;
  padding: 3px 0 ;
  margin-top:6px;
}
#listLumira li a:hover, #navigation li a:focus, #navigation li a:active {
  background:   #483D8B ;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   text-transform: uppercase;

}

#img  img:hover, #navigation li a:focus, #navigation li a:active {
  background:   #483D8B ;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

my problem is in the third Id call in my CSS...
the point is to transform #navigation list while cursor is on the #img.
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: can you add your full code in jsfiddle? or here?

Comment: Styling `text-transform` on the selector `#img  img:hover` makes no sense, as images don't have text nodes.

Comment: If you are loading that html in a loop, I would refrain from giving an id of '#img' and rather give a class. Multiple ids on a page is semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to do this CSS only is not going to work, unless you try to hack the system. CSS only supports `:hover` child selectors if the element is actually a child element, but that is not possible in `img` tags.

You could use JavaScript for this though.

```js
$('img').on('mouseover', function(){
  $('p').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
});

$('img').on('mouseout', function(){
  $('p').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>text</p>

<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
```